# Assign struct fieldname values to the column pyspark

Tags: pyspark, struct

I am having a scenario where I need to assign the value of fieldname in an array of struct to the column in pyspark

Below is the schema

```
root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Details: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- College: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Users: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Department: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
```

So here I need to assign value of **College** to **Details** and Department/ID to **Users**

TIA.

Comment: `Details` could be an array of string, but how `Users` can be an array of something else not struct while you have 2 fields? Can you show an example of your expected output?

Comment: *Users* is an array of struct. Based on the condition I need to assign either *Department or ID* to the Users column

Answer (score 0):

You can just select the struct's subfield and replace old columns

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('Details', F.col('Details.College'))
    .withColumn('Users', F.col('Users.Department')) # change to `Users.ID` if you want
    .show(10, False)
)
```

Comment: Yeah. I am looking for an alternative for explode where `Details` column can be changed to `stringtype` holding just the value rather than array

Comment: so which element of `Details` array would you pick? The first one?